# Is it possible to Build and Run Cassandra from source code on Win 10

Tags: cassandra, operating-system, jvm

I have built source code from apache Cassandra repository succesfully and move all sciprts from release/bin to the corresponding built directory.

When I run the `cassandra.bat`,  error info still occurs. I tried to fix them one by one, including complement additional jar(jamm) from release zip, copy all files to the collacated directory from release/conf except for `cassandra.yaml` which contains "invalid entry" as the jvm reported.

Still I cannot run the Cassandra I built.

Now I am really disturbed that since the JVM is OS dependent, and I have built the source code and fixed the scripts and configuration files, why I still cannot run the Cassandra I built ?

Or one more concise question: Is there any way to build and run a cassandra from souce code on win 10 ?

Any help is sincerely appreciated, thank you.

Eidited:

Now I know Cassandra is going to remove Windows scripts for lack of test and maintenance thanks to informative comments.

But I still cannot figure out why, isn't Cassandra a process above JVM? Is it for the reason that Cassandra utilise some system call that is system dependent ?

Comment: Windows support in Cassandra is in process of removal: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt ! But may I ask that why Cassandra needs extra maintenance even though it runs on JVM ? Is it because Cassandra uses some JNI or other system call that is OS dependent ?

Comment: yes, it requires JNI stuff. You can look into follow up Jira that actually remove Windows-specific classes

Comment: This is probably a better question for the dev@cassandra.apache.org mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexOtt , the reason why C* is not that platform independent is at least partilaly based on the File System of the OS. I may quote some words from the mailing threads.

from : https://lists.apache.org/thread/cpbpx74ysrs7xwgklpx2wh6003jms260

> From: Joshua McKenzie jm...@apache.org
> Date: Thursday, 30 July 2020 at 15:56
> To: dev@cassandra.apache.org de...@cassandra.apache.org
> Subject: Re: [Discussion] Windows support
>
> I was the one that got Windows fully supported in 2014/2015 for context.
> I say we pull support out. The way NTFS treats hard links (i.e. inability
> to delete junctions if someone has a handle open to them even w/the right
> flags if the file is memory mapped) is just a major headache in terms of
> the way C*'s file I/O operates.